# RelativeSource binding doesn't work when ListBox source items are embedded in xaml

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Is there a specific way of defining `ItemsSource` when items are provided in the control? In this code, the first `TextBlock` of the data template shows a value, the second not.

```
<ListBox x:Name="myList">
    <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Can</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Keep</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>A</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Secret</ListBoxItem>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData},
                                          StringFormat=' (previous: {0})'}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If I set the items list in a resource and set the `ItemsSource` property to refer to the list resource, both bindings work:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyStringList x:Key="lst">
        <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Can</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Keep</sys:String>
        <sys:String>A</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Secret</sys:String>
    </local:MyStringList>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="myList" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=lst}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ItemTemplate isn't used at all, since you are directly adding ListBoxItems to the `Items` collection (btw. not `ItemsSource`).

The ItemTemplate is only applied for items that are no UI elements, or more precisely for items for which the [`IsItemItsOwnContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.isitemitsowncontaineroverride?view=netframework-4.8) method returns `false`.

In this case, a `ListBoxItem` container is generated, and the value of the ListBox's `ItemTemplate` property is applied to its `ContentTemplate` property.

So this would work:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myList">
    <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Can</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Keep</sys:String>
    <sys:String>A</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Secret</sys:String>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData},
                                          StringFormat=' (previous: {0})'}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Of course, there is little need for a template when an item is already a UIElement or equivalent.